# Printing odd prime every 100K primes found

Tags: primes, potion

I'm trying to make a program that print every 100K-th odd prime number until 10M using [Potion](https://github.com/perl11/potion), my code:

```
last = 3 
res = (last) # create array
loop:
   last += 2
   prime = true 
   len = res length -1
   i = 0
   while(i<len):
      v = res at(i)
      if(v*v > last): break.
      if(last%v == 0): prime = false, break.
      i += 1
   .
   if(prime):
          res append(last)
          if(res size % 100000 == 0): last print.
          if(last>9999999): break.
   .
.
```

But this gives `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, I wonder what's wrong?

For reference, the working [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) version:

```
res = [last=3]
loop do 
   last += 2
   prime = true
   res.each do |v|
          break if v*v > last 
          if last % v == 0 
        prime = false 
        break
      end
   end
   if prime
     res << last 
     puts last if res.length % 100000 == 0 
     break if last > 9999999
   end
end
```

The output should be:

```
1299721
2750161
4256249
5800139
7368791
8960467
```

and no, this is not a homework, just out of curiosity.

Comment: BTW: potion needs 6m31.999s with the fixed version. The algo is not really good, but here the vm is to blame. Horrible.

ruby needs only 32s

Comment: And for reference: I was working on this faster primes example:
https://github.com/perl11/potion/blob/master/example/prime.pn

Comment: great but that's the point of benchmark ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you found it out by yourself, great! 
`println` is called `say` in potion.
And it crashed in `res size`.

E.g. use this for debbugging:

  `rm config.inc
  make DEBUG=1
  bin/potion -d -Dvt example/100thoddprime.pn`

and then press enter until you get to the crash.

`(example/100thoddprime.pn:18):           res append(last)`

`>`

    `; (3, 5)
[95] getlocal 1 1   ; (3, 5)
[96] move     2 1   ; (3, 5)
[97] loadk    1 5   ; size
[98] bind     1 2   ; function size()
[99] loadpn   3 0   ; nil
[100] call     1 3Segmentation fault`

so size on res returned nil, and this caused the crash.

And instead of `last print, "\n" print.`
Just do `last say.`
This came from perl6 syntax, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I forgot to change from `res length -1` to `res length` when changing from `0 to len (i)`, because this syntax not recognized as a loop (failed to receive `break`).

```
last = 3
res = (last)
loop:
   last println
   last += 2
   prime = true
   len = res length
   i = 0
   while(i<len):
      v = res at(i)
      if(v*v > last): break.
      if(last%v == 0): prime = false, break.
      i += 1
   .
   if(prime):
      res append(last)
      if(res length % 100000 == 0): last print, "\n" print.
      if(last>9999999): break.
   .
.
```